# Hidden Field/Tag in TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I want to pass a value that will be generated at runtime,through a TextView. the text property is used for some other data and the data that I want to pass will not be displayed. So, it's a like a hidden tag. Is it possible to do with TextView? If so, which property of the TextView.

For simplicity's sake imagine I pull the ID and TEXT from the data table. Now the TEXT is displayed on the TextView but when I want to pass the reference to that particular row of the table to some other function I want to pass the ID as an argument/handle. So, the ID will be hidden and associated with the TextView. How can I do it? If not possible can you suggest any alternative to accomplish this? BTW, the TextView is embedded within a ListView.

Adapter code :

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM EmpTable", null);

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.item_row, 
                cursor, 
                new String[] {"Emp_Name"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.txtEmployee});
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try [setTag(int, Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [getTag(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28int%29). There are even versions that don't take a key, if you just want to store one value. From the docs:

> Sets the tag associated with this
>   view. A tag can be used to mark a view
>   in its hierarchy and does not have to
>   be unique within the hierarchy. Tags
>   can also be used to store data within
>   a view without resorting to another
>   data structure.

So you can do:

```
textView.setTag(myValue);
```

and get it back later with:

```
myValue = textView.getTag();
```

Since the interface uses `Object`, you will need to add casts. For example, if your value is an `int`:

```
textView.setTag(Integer.valueOf(myInt));
```

and:

```
myInt = (Integer) textView.getTag();
```

**Edit** - to subclass and add the tag, use:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_row,
        cursor, new String[] {"Emp_Name"}, new int[] R.id.txtEmployee}) {
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        view.setTag(someValue);
        return view;
    }
};
```

Comment: This looks good. However, I am still stuck as I am not sure if this can be used with a list adapter?  You know where we use a cursor and an adapter to populate a ListView by supplying the resource id of the textView like new int[] {R.id.txtEmployee} ? In what way can I set the Tag for the TextView that is returned by the cursor before I set the adapter for the ListView?

Comment: Can you post the line you use to create your adapter? From that I can write the subclassing code you need to add the tag.

Comment: You can subclass the adapter and override `getView` to set the tag.

Comment: This is what I am using now. This only include the Emp_Name as I don't know how to pass the _id to the adapter.  BTW, I updated the code in my original post for better visbility.                                                                   cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM EmpTable", null);   . 

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this, 
    R.layout.item_row, 
    cursor, 
    new String[] {"Emp_Name"}, 
    new int[] R.id.txtEmployee});

Comment: Thank you so much. That did it. I was really stuck with it as I am still kind of beginner in java and android. Guess I gotta learn harder :-). Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `setTag()` and `getTag()`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to have your ListAdapter inflate a layout instead of a TextView for each item of the list. Then you can have other (invisible) fields hidden in the layout.

The xml might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/visible_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Visible text"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/hidden_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hidden value"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In retrospect, I think Ted's answer is more suited to what you need. Mine is better suited for information one might need to show/hide dynamically at runtime.